# Bash array: remove elements starting with dash (-)

Tags: arrays, bash, sed, grep

Say I have the following array, where the elements may be ordered in *any* way:

```
items=('this-item' 'that-item' '-fd')
```

How do I remove the one *starting* with dash (`-fd`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way:

```
for i in "${!items[@]}"; do
    [[ ${items[i]} == -* ]] && unset "items[$i]"  ## Or unset 'items[i]'
done

# Optionally re-align indices:
items=("${items[@]}")
```

If you just want to remove the third element anyway you can just have:

```
items=("${items[@]:0:2}")
```

Or just

```
unset 'items[2]'
```

If you have more than 3 elements:

```
items=(1 2 3 4 5)
items=("${items[@]:0:2}" "${items[@]:3}")
```

Or just

```
unset 'items[2]'; items=("${items[@]}")
```

Note that array indices start at 0. It may also be different if some indices were deleted.

Comment: I italicized the "_any_ way" in the question.

Comment: @Det The first part of my answer answers that. Please try it.

Comment: Yes, just mentioning.